# Side by side divs not aligning

Tags: html, css

I've created two divs that are sitting side by side by this recommended method I've found here which is the display: inline-block. But I'm having problem with the other div being lower than the first one. Even if they are the same size, the second one still is positioned lower than the first one. Here is the CSS code:

```
#left {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40%;
}
#right{
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 40%;
 border-left: 2px double #cccccc;
}
.container2 {
 height: auto;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container2">
    <div id="left">
        <p><h4>Adress</h4></p>
        238 Smoky Hollow St.<br>
        Billerica, MA 01821<br>
        817-439-3708<br>
        MarioEisenhower@jourrapide.com
    </div>

    <div id="right">                            
        <h4><p>Working hours</p></h4>
        Monday - Friday  08:00 – 20:00<br>
        Saturday    08:00 – 14:00<br>                           
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jsfiddle showing the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/dr0es1kg/1/

Could it be because of the  tags or something else that is missing?

Comment: You put a paragraph tag (<p>) around the <h4> tag on the left div, but not on the right side. Overall your HTML is not valid, fix this and the divs will be aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `#left` and `#right`.

```css
#left {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
}

#right {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 40%;
  border-left: 2px double #cccccc;
}

.container2 {
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div id="left">
    <h4>Adress</h4>
    238 Smoky Hollow St.<br> Billerica, MA 01821<br> Tel: 817-439-3708<br> MarioEisenhower@jourrapide.com
  </div>

  <div id="right">


    <h4>
      Working hours
    </h4>
    Monday - Friday 08:00 – 20:00<br> Saturday 08:00 – 14:00<br>

  </div>
</div>
```

or use `flex`

```css
#left {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}

#right {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  border-left: 2px double #cccccc;
}

.container2 {
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div id="left">
    <h4>Adress</h4>
    238 Smoky Hollow St.<br> Billerica, MA 01821<br> Tel: 817-439-3708<br> MarioEisenhower@jourrapide.com
  </div>

  <div id="right">


    <h4>Working hours</h4>
    Monday - Friday 08:00 – 20:00<br> Saturday 08:00 – 14:00<br>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you drag it smaller you can see it will also affect the left div. I'd add `vertical-align: top;` to both divs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) specification. I rewrited above snippet with flexbox to show you how you can use it. Basically you have to add on parent container display: flex; and set a direction with flex-direction: row;(for your case).

```css
#left {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}

#right {
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
  border-left: 2px double #cccccc;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div id="left">
    <h4>Adress</h4>
    238 Smoky Hollow St.<br> Billerica, MA 01821<br> Tel: 817-439-3708<br> MarioEisenhower@jourrapide.com
  </div>

  <div id="right">


    <h4>
      Working hours
    </h4>
    Monday - Friday 08:00 – 20:00<br> Saturday 08:00 – 14:00<br>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a real sense they are actually not the same size

`#right` has a `border-left:2px` which adds to the `40%`this is most likely the cause. ALSO TRY FLOATING THE `IDS`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why they aren't aligning vertically is first of all because they have different amounts of content (`#left` has more than `#right`). Secondly, since you have set them to display as `inline-block`, they are positioned as an `inline` object would be. **Adding `vertical-align: top` to them should remedy this issue.**

An easier way to automatically stretch sibling elements to an appropriate height is to use `flexbox` with its property `align-items: stretch`.